# USB printer works only with one notebook

Tags: printing, hp

I have an HP LaserJet P1005. Printer is connected by USB and configured with hplib driver. I have to notebooks running Ubuntu.

Notebook A

- Ubuntu 10.10
- After connecting printer is doing some initialization work
- Printing works without problems

Notebook B

- Ubuntu 11.10
- After connecting printer is quite, no initialization
- No errors in syslog
- Print jobs are send to the printer but printer does not execute the jobs, no error popups or error messages in syslog
- After connecting the printer to notebook A and and back to notebook B printing works fine an notebook B

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

After installing the "HPLIP plugin" the printer works:

HPLIP Plugin Download:

- 3.11.10: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web....10-plugin.tar
- 3.11.7 for Ubuntu 11.10: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web...1.7-plugin.tar

To install, extract the tar, make the content executable an run it as root:

```
tar xvf hplip-3.11.7-plugin.tar
chmod 775 hplip-3.11.7-plugin.run
sudo ./hplip-3.11.7-plugin.run
```

To configure hplip printers you can also install the HPLIP Gui from the repo, package name is *hplip-gui*:

```
sudo aptitude install hplip-gui
```